# Compile a page twice, one normal and one mirrored

Tags: compiling, minipage, page

There is a package that compiles every page with a vertical mirrored page, like in the images?

Original one:
[image]

Intended one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

\huge Hello word

\newpage

Hello world again

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know any automatic solution, but with `pdfpages` you can compound the desired output.

Comment: This should be possible by setting up the page dimensions to only cover the bottom half of the page and then during the output routine do the mirroring. But there is no package that already ships this functionality, afaik. So to get this effect would require a bit of setup.